# How to detect the account used for crawling?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, crawling

I am trying to crawl a network shared folder and I would like to find out which account SharePoint is using for the crawl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the default content Access account.

- Login to **SharePoint Central admin** with **farm admin account**
- goto `Application management > Manage Service Application`...On this click on the **Search Service Application**.
- On this page, Under the System Status look for "**Default content Access Account**", the value infront of this is the account.
  [image]

Comment: Also look for any Crawl Rules that may override the default account.

Comment: Thx ! I used the one that I saw but still nothing...when I give Everyone the read right it crawls when I put SPServices (the one that is used for search) I get access denied.